Programming about the game 'nim'
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

bool winning(int x, int y, int z)
//x,y,z = number of stones in the 3 piles.
//returns true if this is a winning position.
{
    if (x==0 && y==0 && z==0) return false;    // base case

    for (int i=1; i<=x; ++i)                   // Pick i stones from pile 1
        if (!winning(x-i, y, z)) return true;  // if a losing next state is found

    for (int i=1; i<=y; ++i)                   // Pick i stones from pile 2
        if (!winning(x, y-i, z)) return true;  // if a losing next state is found

    for (int i=1; i<=z; ++i)                   // Pick i stones from pile 3
        if (!winning(x, y, z-i)) return true;  // if a losing next state is found

    return false;                              // if all next states are winning
}
int main() {
    int x,y,z;
    cout << "Give the number of stones in the 3 piles: ";
    cin >> x >> y >> z;
    if (winning(x,y,z)) cout << "Wins." << endl;
    else cout << "Loses." << endl;
}

What is the code actually doing? Every loop will ultimately end at x=0, y=0 and z=0. Then how the program differentiates different values. (It may be that I have not understood some use of general commands like 'return', please explain it too.)

It's c++ with simplecpp package added. So don't mind the syntax.

what is "simplecpp" ? Calling main_program "simple" is somewhat weird. Simple it would be to show the actual code rather than hiding it behind silly macros

anyhow, you are asking us what the code does but at the same time we shouldnt mind the syntax which is not proper C++. We cannot tell you what the code does unless you show us that header. I am picking on details, but -well- details do matter

@463035818_is_not_an_ai it's a package installed to teach freshmen the c++

the problem is, it is teaching you not-c++. main_program is not c++. Not including the right headers is not c++.

So... You wish to know the Secret of Nim... It's Mice.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Yes, it will be int main(). Except that, everything is as it should be. Please focus on its semantics.

"Every loop will ultimately end at x=0, y=0 and z=0."  how do you know? I dont think so. You should use a debugger to see what is actually happening

What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?

I actually do not understand the question "how the program differentiates different values."  what different values?

I mean serisouly. After having critized everything I found to critize about the question I am now in the helping mode. And the best help you can get is from your debugger. Someone else explaining you what the code does will only steal you a great opportunity to learn how to use a debugger.

If you cannot use a debugger because the system you're using will not allow it, copy the code onto a system that does let you use a debugger, and use the debugger. If you STILL cannot use a debugger, add more print statements to the code to provide you with the diagnostic information that the debugger would have given you.  A couple cout << x << ','<< y << ','<< z << '\n';s in strategic spots in winning will tell you almost everything you want to know.

@KeShAw "So don't mind the syntax." -- Ignoring what you should do, think about this from a diplomatic mindset. From a reader's perspective, the syntax is wonky and there is no motivation to accommodate it, given that readers are volunteers. Down- and close- votes are easy responses to wonkiness. Right or wrong, it happens. On the other hand, you know the syntax is wonky. You know people will mind it. You even know how to make the syntax not-wonky. Yet you don't want to clean it up (and test the code to make sure it still behaves the same). Why? Do you want a poorly-received question?

The rationale of the code is:

If all piles are empty, I have lost. Return false because there is no way to in.
Otherwise, try each legal move. The legal moves are removing one or more stones from one pile, so loops are used to try each possible move. The position that results from a move is tested to see if it has some winning move for the player in that position. If it does not, if it is a forced losing position for the other player, so it is a winning move for me. Return true because there is a winning move.
If none of the legal moves result in a winning move, return false because there is no way to win.

If you still have questions, you should trace the code by executing it manually. Figure out what it does with winning(0, 1, 0) and with winning(1, 1, 1).
